# Issues with absolute path in Php

Tags: php, path, filepath

I am trying to get absolute path of my project using following php code.

`$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."Lapshop";`

Where *Lapshop* is name of my project.

To display logo I have used `<img src="'.$root.'/images/logoc.png">`

After checking in source complete path is shown as:

`C:/wamp/www/Lapshop/images/logoc.png`

But image fails to appear. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server doesn't access to your C:/
You should use relative path

```
<img src="../Lapshop/images/logoc.png">
```

or

```
"<img src='http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/Lapshop/images/logoc.png'>"
```

Comment: Am on windows developing using WAMP.

Comment: Your local apache still doesn't access to your local disk, it has access to the directory www

Comment: So how to access www/Lapshop when am deep within 2 folder.

Comment: I just editeed my answer, sorry, for absolute path you can use "<img src='http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/Lapshop/images/logoc.png'>"

Comment: For relative path you can use ../../Lapshop/images/logoc.png